# How to filter json data with data range (React JS)

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have JSON data with ISO date, and I want to get all the data that "date_created" is within the date range, regardless of what the time is, and without modifying the value of the JSON data.

date range sample:
start date: 2021-05-25T16:00:00.000Z,
end date: 2021-05-28T16:00:00.000Z

sample of JSON data:

```
{
            "article_title": null,
            "article_source_url": "ttgindia.travel",
            "article_authors": null,
            "article_sections": [],
            "article_publish_date": null,
            "article_content": null,
            "article_images": null,
            "article_videos": null,
            "article_media_type": "Web",
            "article_ad_value": 0,
            "article_pr_value": 0,
            "article_language": "en",
            "article_status": "Error",
            "article_error_status": "No content",
            "article_source_from": "NodeJS Static Scraper",
            "created_by": "System",
            "updated_by": "Python Global Scraper",
            "is_in_mysql": false,
            "_id": "60ade881da0fa204f1729e79",
            "section": "5f2d7fd8591132886d070d10",
            "article_url": "http://www.ttgindia.travel/2019/04/29/advertise-with-us",
            "date_created": "2021-05-28T02:20:45.856Z",
            "date_updated": "2021-05-27T06:30:45.856Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "article_title": null,
            "article_source_url": "ttgindia.travel",
            "article_authors": null,
            "article_sections": [],
            "article_publish_date": null,
            "article_content": null,
            "article_images": null,
            "article_videos": null,
            "article_media_type": "Web",
            "article_ad_value": 0,
            "article_pr_value": 0,
            "article_language": "en",
            "article_status": "Done",
            "article_error_status": "No content",
            "article_source_from": "NodeJS Static Scraper",
            "created_by": "System",
            "updated_by": "Python Global Scraper",
            "is_in_mysql": false,
            "_id": "60ade881da0fa204f1729e79",
            "section": "5f2d7fd8591132886d070d10",
            "article_url": "http://www.ttgindia.travel/2019/04/29/advertise-with-us",
            "date_created": "2021-05-27T07:20:45.856Z",
            "date_updated": "2021-05-27T06:30:45.856Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "article_title": null,
            "article_source_url": "ttgindia.travel",
            "article_authors": null,
            "article_sections": [],
            "article_publish_date": null,
            "article_content": null,
            "article_images": null,
            "article_videos": null,
            "article_media_type": "Web",
            "article_ad_value": 0,
            "article_pr_value": 0,
            "article_language": "en",
            "article_status": "Error",
            "article_error_status": "No content",
            "article_source_from": "NodeJS Static Scraper",
            "created_by": "System",
            "updated_by": "Python Global Scraper",
            "is_in_mysql": false,
            "_id": "60ade881da0fa204f1729e79",
            "section": "5f2d7fd8591132886d070d10",
            "article_url": "http://www.ttgindia.travel/2019/04/29/advertise-with-us",
            "date_created": "2021-05-27T07:20:45.856Z",
            "date_updated": "2021-05-27T06:30:45.856Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "article_title": null,
            "article_source_url": "ttgindia.travel",
            "article_authors": null,
            "article_sections": [],
            "article_publish_date": null,
            "article_content": null,
            "article_images": null,
            "article_videos": null,
            "article_media_type": "Web",
            "article_ad_value": 0,
            "article_pr_value": 0,
            "article_language": "en",
            "article_status": "Error",
            "article_error_status": "No content",
            "article_source_from": "NodeJS Static Scraper",
            "created_by": "System",
            "updated_by": "Python Global Scraper",
            "is_in_mysql": false,
            "_id": "60ade881da0fa204f1729e79",
            "section": "5f2d7fd8591132886d070d10",
            "article_url": "http://www.ttgindia.travel/2019/04/29/advertise-with-us",
            "date_created": "2021-05-27T06:30:45.856Z",
            "date_updated": "2021-05-27T06:30:45.856Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "article_title": null,
            "article_source_url": "ttgindia.travel",
            "article_authors": null,
            "article_sections": [],
            "article_publish_date": null,
            "article_content": null,
            "article_images": null,
            "article_videos": null,
            "article_media_type": "Web",
            "article_ad_value": 0,
            "article_pr_value": 0,
            "article_language": "en",
            "article_status": "Error",
            "article_error_status": "No content",
            "article_source_from": "NodeJS Static Scraper",
            "created_by": "System",
            "updated_by": "Python Global Scraper",
            "is_in_mysql": false,
            "_id": "60ade881da0fa204f1729e79",
            "section": "5f2d7fd8591132886d070d10",
            "article_url": "http://www.ttgindia.travel/2019/04/29/advertise-with-us",
            "date_created": "2021-05-26T06:19:45.856Z",
            "date_updated": "2021-05-26T06:20:59.828Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `data` variable holds all the data

```
data.filter(item => new Date(item.date_created).getTime() > new Date(start_date).getTime() && new Date(item.date_created).getTime() < new Date(end_date).getTime())
```